# PHP get element using a known attribute

Tags: php, loops

So lets say I have:

```
<?php
    $template = '<img src="{image}" editable="all image_all" />';
    $template .= '<div>';
    $template .= '<img src="{image}" editable="yes" />';
    $template .= '</div>';
?>
```

Now what I would like is to make the script go through all the elements containing the {image} src and checking to see if any of them have the

```
editable="all"
```

attribute.

If so: get the second editable attribute e.g.

```
image_all
```

And include that into the src.

Comment: Have you looked into php dom parser? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Try [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Use PHP [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). It will work nicely for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Use rather the [simple HTML dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), it's simpler to use IMO

Comment: Looks like the developer of SHDP has paid 'SO' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be simplified with the use of a library suggested on comments, [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

It is as easy as this:

```
$images = array(); //an array for your images with {image} in src
$html = "...";
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
    if($element->src == '{image}') {
        //add to the collection
        $images[] = $element;
    }
    //Also you can compare for the editable attribute same way as above.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get second editable attr and save it in an array like $src so check this code:

```
$content=new DOMDocument();
$content->loadHTML($template);
$elements=simplexml_import_dom($content); 
$images=$elements->xpath('//img');
foreach ($images as $img) {
    if(preg_match('/all /i', $img['editable']))
        $src[]=substr($img['editable'],4) ;
}
print_r($src);
```

will output:

```
Array ( [0] => image_all )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  include('simple_html_dom.php');
  $html = str_get_html('<div><img src="{image}" editable="all image_all" /><img src="{image}" editable="yes" /></div>');
  $second_args= array();
  foreach($html->find('img[src="{image}"]') as $element){ 
    $editables = explode(' ',$element->editable); 
    if($editables[0] === "all"){ 
        $second_args[] = $editables[1];
    }
  }
  print_r($second_args);
```